# How do I emit print statements to a socket as they happen?

Tags: printing, socket.io, aiohttp

I have an aiohttp/socketio server. I want to emit the print output of a function to a socket client as each print happens.

Here is how I imagine it working:

```
    async def doWork(data):
        // Do 1-2 minutes of work, printing 100-300 times

    def emitPrintStatement(message):
        sio.emit("printStatement", message) 

    @sio.on("workOnSomething")
    async def workOnSomething(sid, data):
        with onPrint(emitPrintStatement):
            doWork(data)
```

Emitting at the end of the `doWork` would not fit my problem as doWork can take 1-2 minutes.

I'm reusing old `doWork` code, so I'd ideally like to avoid refactoring every `print(...)` call into an `sio.emit(...)`. `doWork` is also a part of a cli, making the print statements necessary. If possible, I'd also like to avoid needing to add `flush` to every single print call, if that is also a solution.

Is such a thing possible?